# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout with custom View

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm following the Cheesesquare example project to understand the new design material library.

I'm wondering if there's a way to use a custom view (like Telegram) with ImageView, title and subtitle instead of the simple Title provided by CollapsingToolbarLayout widget.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` containing an `ImageView` first and then a `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextView`s?

Comment: I've tried, but my purpose is the replacement the Title with my CustomView  to preserve the animation of the title in the toolbar.

Comment: @shkschneider would you explain a bit more. i want to use

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and spend many hours trying to find a solution. My solution was to add the collapsing Views (ImageView and TextView) inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and then handle the transition in code. This way it's more flexible and simpler than extending from CollapsingToolbarLayout.

First you'll need to add your Views inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the parallax properties:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop:"80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.8"/> //set vertical transition here
```

Then set the scaling of the Views with the help of an `OnOffsetchangeListner`:

```
  private static final float SCALE_MINIMUM=0.5f;
  appBarLayout.setOnWorkingOffsetChange(new  ControllableAppBarLayout.OnWorkingOffsetChange() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChange(int offSet, float collapseDistance) {
            imageView.setScaleX(1 + (collapseDistance * SCALE_MINIMUM));
            imageView.setScaleY(1 + (collapseDistance * SCALE_MINIMUM));

            textView.setScaleX(1 + (collapseDistance * SCALE_MINIMUM));
            textView.setScaleY(1 + (collapseDistance * SCALE_MINIMUM));

            // You can also setTransitionY/X, setAlpha, setColor etc.
        }
    });
```

Somehow the default `offsetChangedListener` didn't work properly for me (you probably still should try it with the default listener first), so I used the `ControllableAppBarLayout` from https://gist.github.com/blipinsk/3f8fb37209de6d3eea99 and added the following:

```
private OnWorkingOffsetChange onWorkingOffsetChange;

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        onWorkingOffsetChange.onOffsetChange(i, (float) i / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
    }
}

public void setOnWorkingOffsetChange(OnWorkingOffsetChange listener) {
    this.onWorkingOffsetChange = listener;
}

public interface OnWorkingOffsetChange {
    void onOffsetChange(int offSet, float collapseDistance);
}
```

The only problem is, that you would need to set 
     `app:contentScrim="#00000000"` (transparent)
for your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, so your views are still visible when the toolbar is collapsed. If you really need the collapsing-background effect I'm sure you could "fake" this by setting the alpha of a background ImageView in the `OffsetChangeListener`. ;)

Comment: would you please explain a bit more. i have the same problem, i just want to use an icon and a title in the centre of `CollapsingToolBarLayout` when i scroll up than the icon must fly to toolbar's left side where normally the app icon exists and the title is in the right side of icon.

Answer (score 2):

From the widget itself there doesn't seem to be a way to enable this directly, like it was possible to add custom views to the Toolbar.

What you could try to do however, is open the source of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout.class` and check out how the `CollapsingTextHelper.class` is used to have the title set. You could try to make your own widget by extending from the the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

These links can help you out with creating custom components/views, if you haven't created them before:
[Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

I haven't tried this yet, but it's actually  something I was thinking about trying to achieve a similar solution as you are looking for. Steps I tihkn I would follow, so far:

1. Create custom attributes for subtitle settings in `attrs.xml`
2. Create your own `MyCollapsingToolbarLayout` by extending the original one.
3. Make sure to call `super` in the constructors, so the original component will stay intact.
4. Create a `subtitleTextHelper` by adding a new `CollapsingTextHelper` to your component.
5. Override `onDraw` to actually draw your subtitle.
6. Update the layout containing your `CollapingsToolbarLayout` with your subtitle attributes (default styling and such, maybe a fixed subtitle Text).
7. Apply the changes in the `Activity` containing your `CollapsingToolbar`. (Convert `CollapsingToolbarlayout` to `MyCollapingsToolbarLayout`, set subtitles, extra custom settings, etc).
8. Cross fingers, test.

Going to have a look at it now.

Comment: It was a really hard work. CollapsingToolbarLayout is a terrible widget.

Comment: @StingRay5 Can you help me what to do inside onDraw()?
Or please share your code.

Answer (score 2):

Going to edit Christopher's answer slightly to show how you can get your custom view to not disappear on collapse:

<s>First you'll need to add your Views inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the parallax properties:</s>

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop:"80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.8"/> //set vertical transition here
```

Instead add the custom view's programmatically and it won't disappear on collapse. For example here is a view that contains a title and a subtitle:

```
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(mActivity);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);


    // Create new LinearLayout
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    frameLayoutParams =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPixels(78));
    frameLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    // Add textviews
    final TextView textView1 = new TextView(mActivity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    frameLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    textView1.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    textView1.setText("Title");
    textView1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
    textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
    linearLayout.addView(textView1);


    final TextView textView2 = new TextView(mActivity);
    linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView2.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    textView2.setText("Subtitle");
    textView2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
    textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
    linearLayout.addView(textView2);

    frameLayout.addView(linearLayout);


    collapsingToolbar.addView(frameLayout);
    final float SCALE_MIN=0.4f;
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offSet) {
            float collapsedRatio = (float) offSet / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            linearLayout.setScaleX(1 + (collapsedRatio * SCALE_MIN));
            linearLayout.setScaleY(1 + (collapsedRatio * SCALE_MIN));
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPixels(78));
            frameLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            frameLayoutParams.setMargins(Math.round(dpToPixels(48) * (1+collapsedRatio)), 0, 0, Math.round(dpToPixels(15) * collapsedRatio));
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
            // You can also setTransitionY/X, setAlpha, setColor etc.
        }
    });
```

/////

```
float lastCollapsedRatio = -2;
```

////

```
private int dpToPixels(int padding_in_dp){
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px = (int) (padding_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
    return padding_in_px;
}
```

Comment: Great trick. Except that I suddenly got my logs filled with the following. Any ideas on how to avoid that? (Gah, why can't SO comments support line breaks?)
`requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout{a9c7244 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-1440,405 #7f1100fb app:id/collapsingToolbarLayout} during layout: running second layout pass`  
`requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{4058f2d V.E...... ......I. 168,132-1440,405} during layout: running second layout pass`

Comment: I added a check to see if `collapsedRatio` actually has changed and only do the scaling in those cases. That made all the complaining about second layout pass disappear.

Comment: I haven't used this code in a while. But I do remember encountering that. Where did you add the check? I can update my answer. @RoySolberg