# CollapsingToolbarLayout with multiline title

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

Is it possible to make `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s expanded title text wraps across several lines (similar to `TextView.maxLines` attribute)?

Comment: No. I'm setting `app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"` to make title's text smaller as workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I did this with help from this library

https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar

add the library to your project and replace the CollapsingToolbarLayout with net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 2):

[In 2020](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/413), the feature you desired was added to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. To activate it, simply use:

```
    app:maxLines="3"
```

Here's what it'll look like:

[image: A multiline header title in an Android activity.]

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution on [Android CollapsingToolbarLayout with custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886216/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-custom-view/32332261#32332261).

You can add the TextView, instead of a title inside your CollapsingToolbarLayout and change size/transition/color etc. with the help of the onOffsetChangeListner.